# symfony 5.1: how to define a controller as a service

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, symfony5

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to Symfony. I am attempting to create a bundle with a controller that accepts a service as a constructor argument; however, I am receiving this error:

```
The controller for URI "/heartbeat" is not callable: Controller 
"Acme\HeartbeatBundle\Controller\HeartbeatController" has 
required constructor arguments and does not exist in the container. 
Did you forget to define the controller as a service?
```

This is the `Resources/config/services.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="acme_heartbeat.service.heartbeat_service"
                 class="Acme\HeartbeatBundle\Service\HeartbeatService">
            <argument type="string" id="heartbeat.address"/>
        </service>
        <service id="acme_heartbeat.controller.heartbeat_controller"
                 class="Acme\HeartbeatBundle\Controller\HeartbeatController">
            <argument type="service" id="acme_heartbeat.service.heartbeat_service"/>
            <tag name="controller.service_arguments" />
        </service>
        ...
    </services>
</container>
```

This is the `Resources/config/routes.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing
        https://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">
    <route id="heartbeat" path="/heartbeat" controller="Acme\HeartbeatBundle\Controller\HeartbeatController::heartbeat" methods="GET" />
</routes>
```

The main Symfony app's `config/routes.yaml`:

```yaml
heartbeat:
    resource: '@AcmeHeartbeatBundle/Resources/config/routes.xml'
```

The `Controller/HeartbeatController.php`:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\HeartbeatBundle\Controller;

use Acme\HeartbeatBundle\Service\HeartbeatService;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class HeartbeatController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __construct(HeartbeatService $hbs)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

This is the `Service/HeartbeatService.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace Acme\HeartbeatBundle\Service;

class HeartbeatService
{
    ...
}
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Symfony 4, the preferred way of service naming is to [use the FQCN](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html#service-naming-conventions) as the service id in order to [ease autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#autowiring-logic-explained). You have used an old-style string id so even though the class matches, when Symfony looks it up by the expected id, it cannot find it.

It's an easy fix, either change the definition to

```
<service id="Acme\HeartbeatBundle\Controller\HeartbeatController">
```

Or add an alias:

```
<service id="Acme\HeartbeatBundle\Controller\HeartbeatController" 
         alias="acme_heartbeat.controller.heartbeat_controller" />
```

You could also change your route definition to the registered service id (`acme_heartbeat.controller.heartbeat_controller::index`), but I'd follow the recommendations and go with the first option.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This gives me a new error: `"Acme\HeartbeatBundle\Controller\HeartbeatController" has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber?`. I've added `<tag name="container.service_subscriber"/>`, but it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: That ^^ was an unrelated issue that I've just corrected. My controller was extending `AbstractController`, which apparently requires a container set. I am using your first suggestion and it is working as expected now. Big thanks!

Comment: I had the exact same issue and now have the 2nd error you mention above, can you share what the fix for that was?  Thanks

Comment: @LeeTee If your controller extends `AbstractController` it should get auto tagged. It could be a mismatch between the path/filename and the namespace/classname. Are you working with a bundle or a standalone app?

Comment: Its within a bundle so abstractController doesnt work.  Ive created my own query here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68831270/how-to-use-doctrine-in-custom-bundle-controllers-controller-has-required-cons/68832999?noredirect=1#comment121660052_68832999  If you could have  look and see if you can spot anything obvious that would be much appreciated :)